# How to register a hotkey for (LETTER) and for SHIFT+(LETTER) at the same time

Tags: c#, keyboard, hotkeys

I'm building an application in C# to change the keyboard output for some keys
using globl hotkeys.
when I register a hotkey for a key  and then another hotkey for that key + modifier only the last one works
for example
if I do

```
RegisterHotKey(MyForm.Handle, 100, 0, (int)Keys.T); // T
RegisterHotKey(MyForm.Handle, 200, 4, (int)Keys.T); // Shift + T
```

it capture only Shift + T press.

And when I do

```
RegisterHotKey(MyForm.Handle, 100, 4, (int)Keys.T); // Shift + T
RegisterHotKey(MyForm.Handle, 200, 0, (int)Keys.T); // T
```

It captures only "T" press

Is there a way to handle the two cases ?

**Update**

that's my code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private KeyHandler ghk;

    public Dictionary<Keys, string> ckeys = new Dictionary<Keys, string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }  

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        registerApp();
    }  


    private void registerKey(Keys k, string o, int m = 0)
    {
        ghk = new KeyHandler(k, this, o, m);
        ghk.Register();
    }

    private void HandleHotkey(Keys id)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(ckeys[id]);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID)
        {
            int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();
            HandleHotkey((Keys)id);
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }


    private void registerApp()
    {
        registerKey(Keys.T, "ت");
        registerKey(Keys.T, "ط", KeyModifier.Shift);
    }


    //Modifiers
    static class KeyModifier
    {
        public static int None = 0;
        public static int Alt = 1;
        public static int Control = 2;
        public static int Shift = 4;
        public static int WinKey = 8;
    }

}


//Class KeyHandler
public class KeyHandler
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private int key;
    private IntPtr hWnd;
    private int id;
    private int modifier;

    public KeyHandler(Keys key, Form1 form, string output, int modifier)
    {
        this.key = (int)key;
        this.modifier = modifier;
        this.hWnd = form.Handle;
        id = this.key;
        form.ckeys[key] = output;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return key ^ hWnd.ToInt32();
    }

    public bool Register()
    {
        return RegisterHotKey(hWnd, id, modifier, key);
    }

    public bool Unregiser()
    {
        return UnregisterHotKey(hWnd, id);
    }
}

//Constants
public static class Constants
{
    //windows message id for hotkey
    public const int WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID = 0x0312;
}
```

Comment: No, that works fine.  You are doing something else wrong, hard to guess what.

Comment: @HansPassant I added my code . Can you Check it Please

Comment: form.ckeys[key] is the bug, key does not include the modifier.  So after you registered T and Shift+T, form.ckeys only contains a single entry.

Comment: You are right , but anyway T and Shift + T should be registred . when I add a messageBox in the HandleHotkey function , It's called only when I press Shift+T

Answer (score -1):

The bug is that T and Shift+T are registred with the same id.
I solved the problem by registring Shift+T with a different id .